# Given current time NSDate, change to midnight and return UNIX time in iOS / Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

Given a NSDate object of current time in user's local time zone, how do I change it to midnight and return UNIX time (seconds since epoch) at 00:00.

For example if current date & time is 20 March 2013 12:42PM, given I have an NSDate object which represents this instant, how do I obtain 1363737600 (20 March 2013 00:00:00) ?

Comment: Use the `timeIntervalSince1970` method.

Comment: Thanks @Perception but that will give me 1363783320 instead of 1363737600 because the time part is taken into account.

Comment: your question is mixing things up. @perception is correct WRT obtaining UNIX time (seconds since epoch) for an `NSDate` instance. You are also asking how change the date to be midnight (presumably also in UTC). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086897/getting-nsdate-for-today-with-000000-as-time.

Comment: Step 1: Write some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option for this is to get the time interval since 1970, then round off the result.

```
time_t unixInterval = [someData timeIntervalSince1970];
time_t unixDate = unixInterval / (24*60*60) * (24*60*60);
```

As long as you do the 2nd line with integer types, you will get the desired result.